# Stabilize a really big drone ascent

Tags: after-effects, stabilisation

I have a 300' ascent with a drone looking at 2 actors lying on the ground. The drone does a bit of drifting and rotating on the way up. I want to stabilize the whole shot to be rock solid. If I use point trackers in AE starting from the first frame, then by the time it gets to the top, the points are very close together, resulting in inaccurate tracking. Can I add points on the way up? Or expand the distance between the points on the way up? Is there a better way? Or am I asking too much? Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Sure! This is a great place to start: